# Prove that $f$ is bounded if it converges as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $x \rightarrow -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \rightarrow 7 $ as $x \rightarrow \infty $ and  $f(x) \rightarrow -25 $ as $x \rightarrow -\infty $ and

Prove that $f$ is a bounded function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: Choose an $N_1$ such that $$x > N_1 \implies |f(x) - 7| < 1$$ and an $N_2$ such that $$x < -N_2 \implies |f(x) + 25| < 1$$

Now use the fact that $[-N_2, N_1]$ is compact.